# Using NSUserDefaults to share data between iOS and watchOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I'm having an issue with storing `NSUserDefault` strings in my iOS application and retrieving them on WatchOS.

I used the following tutorial for creating App Groups & using `NSUserDefaults` for App groups: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

In the end, after creating app groups that didn't seem to have any provisioning errors, and then trying to retrieve my stored string, the value remained `null`. (Even though the value I was storing was definitely not `null`)

Here's my code for storing (in HomeViewController.m):

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
initWithSuiteName:@"APP GROUP ID"];
[myDefaults setObject:totalDonatedString forKey:@"donatedForWatch"];
```

And retrieving (in `InterfaceController.m` in `willActivate`):

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
initWithSuiteName:@"APP GROUP ID"];
NSString *donatedWatchString = [myDefaults objectForKey:@"donatedForWatch"];
NSLog(@"%@", donatedWatchString);
[_totalDonatedLabelWatch setText:donatedWatchString];
```

I'm pretty new to iOS dev/Obj c so any help please!

Comment: You can't share data with watch apps through app groups anymore, that only worked in watchOS 1.  Use the WatchConnectivity framework

Comment: @dan Thanks so much; makes more sense now. I ended up using this guide for anyone else who's interested: https://telliott.io/2015/08/11/how-to-communicate-between-ios-and-watchos2.html

Answer (score 0):

To share data your approach is quiet right by using 'App Group'. Create a header file which is included in main app target. Define a macro which identifying your app group. For example declare a `Constant.h` which included as following

```
#ifndef CONSTANT_H
#define CONSTANT_H

#define SHARED_APP_GROUP @"name_of_your_app_group"

#endif
```

import this file wherever you want to access (in watchos app related files and main app files) the app group.

Answer (score 0):

For WatchOS 2 and greater: https://telliott.io/2015/08/11/how-to-communicate-between-ios-and-watchos2.html

The guide has instructions for Swift and Obj-C

Thanks to @dan!